# ¿Cómo recuperar la sesiones de PHP al enviar datos por ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Estoy usando ajax, para el login, cuando envió la información al archivo `access.php` desde el `login.php` en este archivo `access.php` se almacena varias cosas en sesiones, por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION['logueado'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION["id_usuario"] = $id_usuario;
$_SESSION["captcha"] = $intentos_fallidos;
```

Y, la única forma de yo obtener esos datos de esas sesiones en mi archivo `login.php` es recargando la página, pero eso no tiene sentido, pues si estoy usando ajax, es para evitar eso, entonces me encontré con lo siguiente:

```
$("#logIn").load("#logIn"); //$("body").load("body");
```

Pero lo que hace esto es insertar contenido a otro contenedor, es decir al momento de emplearlo, me aparece dos login insertados en la misma página, como puedo evitar que eso suceda o existe alguna otra manera de actualizar la página sin tener que pasar información de un contenedor a otro como lo hace `.load`

```
.done(function(data) {
    $("#logIn").load("#logIn");
}
```

Comment: solo debes limpiar el campo antes de mostrar el nuevo login document.getElementById("nombredelcampo").value = ""; y luego ya puedes cargarlo, asumiento que ya pusiste session_start() en tu archivo access.php

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener esos datos la respuesta de `login.php` debe ser el contenido de `$_SESSION`, puedes usar `JSON` para este fin:

```
//login.php
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
exit();
```

Los puedes recuperar en en JS de la siguiente manera:

```
//este sería tu llamado para el login
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "logine.php",
  data: { usuario: "Juan", password: "miPasswordEspecial" }
}).done(function(a) {

  console.log(a);   //este sería el contenido de $_SESSION 

});
```

De esta manera tendrías la info en la variable `a` dentro de la funcion anónima en `.done()` y puedes hacer lo que necesites con esos datos.